# How to type a Record with keyof of another record, but allow 0 or more keys

Tags: typescript

TS complains that `b` is missing in foo, but I want just some of the keys in it. How to type it properly?

```
const shape = {a: 1, b:2}

const foo: Record<keyof typeof shape, any> = {
  a: 42,
}

// Error: Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'Record<"a" | "b", any>'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use built-in utility type [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), which turns all fields of an object to optional:

```
const shape = { a: 1, b: 2 };

const foo: Partial<Record<keyof typeof shape, any>> = {
  a: 42,
}; // no error
```